# Is there a putenv() exploit?

Tags: php, exploit

I'm using the following code:

```
$data = json_decode($_GET["payload"]);
$env = $data->env;

putenv("MYENV=".$env);
```

But this function is being exploited. I have no idea how. The attacker can execute any code on my machine (Windows).

Does anybody have an idea how this is possible or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show what he put in `payload`?

Comment: Not at this moment, I will start logging the payload now.

Comment: Why would you let a random internet user set env variables?

Comment: What code follows this? Calling `putenv()` is probably not exploitable on its own, but certain things you do afterwards may be tainted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called ShellShock vulnerability. It basically executes any code the attacker wants if `{ :;};` are included. For example

```
MYENV="{ :; }"; /bin/eject
```

will result in ejecting the dvdrom drive on Linux. So in fact anything is possible here.

Source:

- [one](https://threatpost.com/shellshock-like-weakness-may-affect-windows/108696/)
- [two](https://www.rapid7.com/resources/bashbug-vulnerability-explained/)
- [three](https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about2/)
- [four](http://mashable.com/2014/09/26/what-is-shellshock/#c1d72JzSRaqZ)

Comment: That vulnerability was fixed several years ago.

Comment: He also says this is happening on Windows. PHP doesn't use `bash` to execute shell command on Windows, it should use `cmd.com`

Comment: Barmar, 1. the small command I posted works on Fedora 25, bash 4.3.43. The release date was on 2016-10-09; 2. ShellShock works on windows (this can be googled). With limits? Maybe. Enough to upload a root kit? Maybe. Not sure.

Comment: @Barmar you think I should delete the answer? I think this is the closest possible answer, it doesn't look like anything else.

Comment: I know it works on Windows if you're using bash. But PHP won't use bash to execute anything.

Comment: It does seem related to the answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if he's using this. I tried it, but could execute anything.

Comment: @modsfabio my example will not work on windows. It's a linux command. I was aiming at the fact, that a similar example might work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Because some enviroment variable are dangerous like LD_PRELOAD on linux.
Generally this not depend exclusively by putenv, but by other possible vulnerability in you code (e.g. if you exec something that use some magic configuration via enviroment this may led to the exploitaition)